# Forecast in R - Period (h) doesn't change when using external regressors

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to change the number of forecasted period using auto.arima model with regressors. Let's denote `X` as my variable that comes from my `auto.arima` model and `Xreg` my regressors.

When I'm using these commands to get my predicted values: `forecast(X, xreg = Xreg, h=50)` or the command `forecast(X, xreg = Xreg, h=200)`, there is no difference when I'm plotting the results in the forecasted period (I would expect 50 forecasted points from first command and 200 from the second).

However, when I remove the xreg arguments from both my auto.arima model and my forecast command, it works. I'm plotting `forecast(X, h=50)` and I have 50 forecasted points and then I plot `forecast(X, h=200)` and I have 200 forecasted points.

I'm just wondering if it's something that is working as intended or if I missed somethings.

Thanks.

Comment: try `plot(fit, include=200)`. Look at `?plot.forecast`

Comment: You need to have 200 points in your xreg object.  The `h` is essentially ignored when using external regressors.

Comment: 1. I have tried Fernando solution but it doesn't work for me. It doesn't change anything. 

2. If I understand cdeterman comments correctly, the forecasted values length can only be up as my Xreg length?

Comment: Of course...if you have 10 regressor points it will output 10 points. My suggestion was for plotting.

Comment: So If I have 200 days of data WITH a Xreg properties. I can only forecast up to 200 new points. However, if I have 200 days of data WITHOUT a Xreg properties, I can forecast as far as I want? I don't understand why one allows it and the others doesn't. :P